# Run function when inputs are not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's start with the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gytrn/

Here I am mixing angular and jquery like a bad person, I know, but the underlying question is this:

How can I more elegantly execute the javascript to fade in the paragraph once all the inputs are filled in?

Currently the code is as such:

```
$('input').focusout(function(){
    var allInput = $('input')
    var inArr = []
    for (var i = 0; i < allInput.length; i++) {
        inArr.push($('input:eq('+i+')').val().length)
    }
    console.log(inArr);
    if(inArr.sort()[0]===0){

    } else {
        $('p').fadeIn(750)
    }
});
```

It feels very heavy handed and I would like to know a better way. Feel free to ignore the fact that I'm using Angular and that there is an Angular way to do this. I would like to know a vanilla js or js and jquery solution to this problem that is more elegant.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Gytrn/4/

Comment: I like your answer a lot as well adeneo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proposed improvements:

1) Inputs cached once, not every time your handler fires

2) `focusout` handler returns when first empty field found

3) Quick native check of input for emptiness

```
$(function () {
    var allInput = $('input');
    $('input').focusout(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < allInput.length; i++) {
            if (allInput[i].value.length === 0) {
                return;
            }            
        }
        $('p').fadeIn(750);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gytrn/3/)

Comment: Hah. You're right. I hadn't even realized I had put the variable declaration inside the for loop. How silly is that?

Comment: Only issue with this solution is if the user removes text from an input after the paragraph has faded in, the paragraph will still be visible. Not sure if that actually matters.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to do it

```
var inputs = $("input");
inputs.on("change", function () {
    var allFilled = true;
    inputs.each( 
        function(){ 
            if(this.value.length===0){ 
                allFilled = false; 
                return false; //break loop
            }
        } 
    );
    $("#myParagraph").toggle(allFilled);
});
```